# How to check which checkboxes are checked and which are not?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I found on Stackoverflow how to create alert dialog with checkboxes. It worked very well. My problem is, how I can check which of checkboxes are checked or not? I use checkboxes to set filename of textfile, which is being saved.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {" Custom/Default Filename ", "With Date&Time "," With this device's model "};
// arraylist to keep the selected items
final ArrayList seletedItems=new ArrayList();

AlertDialog dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this)
    .setTitle("Select, what export file's name contains")
    .setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                // write your code when user checked the checkbox
                seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
            } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                  // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                  // write your code when user Uchecked the checkbox
                  seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
              }
           }
       }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  // What I should to in this step, to detect which checkboxes are checked and which are not? That's my problem.                 
                  //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                  //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here
              }
          }).create();
     dialog2.show();
```

Comment: Isn't it why you have the seletedItems there? seletedItems will have the list of checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a generic list, use a list of boolean and store on `ischecked` in it like

```
final List<Boolean> seletedItems = Arrays.asList(false,false,false)
// or final List<Boolean> seletedItems = new ArrayList<>();
// for(int i =0;i<items.length;i++){seletedItems.add(false);}
```

and store the data as corresponding index

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
        seletedItems.set(indexSelected,isChecked);
  // add boolean check at the particular position 
}
```

Note: The size of list is equal to the size of array to keep selection according to position

so assume, user selected 0,2 then `seletedItems` will have

```
index      value
 0          true
 1          false
 2          true
```

You can also use array of `boolean` as well to be more efficient

Comment: Finally, It's working without any errors. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I am glad that I could help, finally I should go to sleep as well :P